# How to open a new view when touching on a uiview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with `UIView` added as subview. Now how do I open a new view when i touch on the view ?

I want new view to appear .before this i have buttons on my view...so button have the method "addtarget perform selector"...from that i am loading a new view

here is an image of my view

[image]

Comment: How do you want the new view to appear? Do you want it to fill the whole window? with animation? or just appear on top of the current view?

Comment: i want a new view to appear...before this i have buttons on my view...so button have the method addtarget perform selector...from that i am loading a new view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example try following code (add it to your view):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [touch tapCount];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    switch (tapCount)
    {
         case 1:
         {
              UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
              view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
              view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

              [self.view addSubview:view];
              [view release];
         }
         break;
    }
}
```